# R:How to eliminate observations in data frame if it shows certain value every year

Tags: r

My dataset is as follows:

```
    ID year mrg_status 
    1  1990     2
    1  1991     2
    1  1992     1
    2  1990     2
    2  1991     2
    3  1990     2
    3  1992     2
    4  1990     2
    4  1991     1
```

What I want to do is: For each ID, if mrg_status is 2 in every year, then eliminate all the observations of this ID. For example: for ID=2, in both 1990 and 1991, its mrg_status are both 2, so we should eliminate all records of ID=2. And same criteria applies to ID=3.The result should look like:

```
    ID year mrg_status
    1  1990  2
    1  1991  2
    1  1992  1
    4  1990  2
    4  1991  1
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far? What did you search?

Comment: What should happen if you have a an ID with a single entry (ID: 5,  year: 1990,  mrg_status: 1) ? Is it deleted or not?

Comment: My dataset all starts with mrg_status = 2... The first answer really works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we check `if` there are `any` elements in 'mrg_status' that is not equal to 2, then get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(any(mrg_status!=2)) .SD, by = ID] 
#     ID year mrg_status
#1:  1 1990          2
#2:  1 1991          2
#3:  1 1992          1
#4:  4 1990          2
#5:  4 1991          1
```

---

The same method can be used with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(any(mrg_status!=2))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `table/subset`

```
 i1 <- !!table(df1$ID, df1$mrg_status!=2)[,2]
 subset(df1, ID %in% names(i1)[i1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `lapply` and `split`. We `split` the data frame based on id's and find the id which has all its `mgr_status` as 2 and then remove all such id's from the original data frame.

```
indx <- lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) prod(x[,3] == 2) == 1)
df[!df$id %in% names(indx[indx == T]), ]

#  id year mgr_status
#1  1 1990          2
#2  1 1991          2
#3  1 1992          1
#8  4 1990          2
#9  4 1991          1
```

Comment: Sorry that it seems it does not work with my data set. It shows 0 rows after applying the second line of command